# Unique value rule for an attribute in yii

Tags: php, yii, unique

I'm new to yii. I have a table called 'member' and when entering values to that through my yii app, the user should not be allowed to insert a member with same NIC.

Is there a default rule for that or should I create a custom rule? Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done like this

```
array('NIC', 'unique',
                    'message'=>'NIC is already in use.'),
```